# How to connect and read response from microservice(TCP) in socket.io

Tags: websocket, tcp, microservices, nestjs, tcpclient

In Nest.js, I am using tcp architecture for microservice communication, in socket.io connection, I am able connect the microservice as show below but I am not able to read the response.

this.client.emit<any, any>('getSingleRoom', payload);

this.client.send({ service: 'getSingleRoom' }, payload).toPromise();

Both the code connect with microservice but, I am not able to read out this response so that I can emit in main server. I am using web socket in nest.js.

Comment: Can't edit because of awaiting approval, But suggest you to Make code line as into code format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.client.send<any, any>('sendMessagesInRoom', pay).toPromise();

Answer (score 0):

You can use firstValueFrom, from rxjs.

```
await firstValueFrom(this.client.send<any, any>('sendMessagesInRoom', pay))
```